# VBA - Counting the number of filled cells in a row

Tags: vba, excel

The following is my code so far. Any tips?

```
 With wSheet
     colCount = .Range(1 & .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
  End With
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
colCount = wSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count
```

(revised)

Comment: It looks like you are mixing your rows and columns?

Answer (score 3):

To get the number of the rightmost filled column:

```
colCount = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

To get the count of non-blank cells, as your title says:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(1).EntireRow.Cells)
```